# Methods from Repository or Service Class in Menu

Tags: java, sql, service, repository

I'm creating simple console app in Java. Nowadays I'm implementing MenuService with one main method and few helpers:

```
 public void mainMenu() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("\n___ CINEMA MENU ___");
                System.out.println("Find all cinemas - 1");
                int decision = UserDataService.getInteger("___ Type option ___");
                switch (decision) {
                    case 0 -> {
                        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                        return;
                    }
                    case 1 -> option1();
                    default -> System.out.println("No option with this number");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new MenuServiceException("Failed");
            }
        }
    }

 private void option1(){
        //do some work
    }
```

From this menu user will be able to perform various operations. Suppose I want to show to user all cinemas from my db when user type 1. I have two ways to do that:

1. Simply implement in the MenuService my CinemaRepository and write in option1 method

`cinemaRepository.findAll()`

2. Implement CinemaService in MenuService and in this CinemaService create a method to find all of my cinemas from db

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CinemaService {

    private final CinemaRepository cinemaRepository;

    public List<Cinema> findAll() {
        return cinemaRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

and after that simply execute in option1 method:

`cinemaService.findAll();`

What is the right way? Execute directly methods from repository in my MenuService or implement CinemaService and hide the method from the repository there.

Thanks for your help! I want to learn good programming practices

Answer (score 1):

Executing the method **cinemaRepository.findAll()** directly inside **option1()** can be done. However, it is not a good idea to expose the data layer directly. Adding a **CinemaService** will benefit in :

1. Added application-level security on the services layer in a way that might not be possible to a data access layer.
2. You can add some validation in your service class.
3. You can play around with the middle layer and prevent unnecessary calls to DB and hence make a minimal number of calls to the DB.
4. It will be extremely helpful when you enhance your application and add some logic before/after making DB hits.

For your case you can try both the methods as you explained but a smarter way would be to go with **CinemaService**